# Change histogram bar colors in Banana

Tags: solr, bigdata, kibana, banana

Is it possible to change the colors of a Banana histogram chart (all histograms have green colors)? I would like to have two histogram charts of different colors but I do not find where the parameter is set in the code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The color of the **histogram bars** is the same as the color of the **query color**, figured in the attached images.

This is how to change the query color

[image]

One example with **red** color:

[image]

Another example with **blue** color:

[image]

We are currently working on supporting **multi-queries in banana 1.5**, and every single query will have different color.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed when the color of the query is updated all histograms will change color. What I was looking for is to define a different color for each histogram. I guess this will be available with the multi-queries feature.

Comment: Yes, It will be available with Multi-queries feature. Stay tuned for it

Comment: That is a really good news! Do you have a date for the next release? And also, if possible, could you tell me which will be the new features? Thanks again!